# Telegraph api query length limitation

Tags: api, telegram

You can't create telegraph pages (through API) that bigger than ~2890 characters!

In the documentation of [telegraph api](http://telegra.ph/api#createPage) declared max field size

```
content (Array of Node, up to 64 KB)
```

I noticed that before you reach 64kb limitation for the 'content' field, you firstly stuck with total query length nginx limitation. If your query length greater than ~3115 characters then nginx throw 400 Bad Request.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/0.3.33</center>
</body>
```

[bad query example](http://telegra.ph/RCForgeReleaseNotes118-02-01-2) If you remove 1 character from content or author name, everything ok.

Right now, through API, you can create very small pages, but no more.

Workaround? Whether there is a normal request with POST or PUT?
I tried to inspect web requests(PUT for editing) that make browser and simulate them, but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they support POST requests: [here is api description](http://telegra.ph/api#Available-methods). Have you tried one?

> We support GET and POST HTTP methods. The response contains a JSON object, which always has a Boolean field ok.

Maybe, you mispelled something? [Here is](http://telegra.ph/api#createPage) a method to create a page, I've just checked it, it works.

Comment: Thunder strike me! I'm a fool!
I do GET requests as shown in the examples.
And did not see in the documentation, that there is a post requests.
Everything was much easier, thank you!